# Custom dynamic nested ul list from a json using a JS for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Hello I am trying to render a dynamic nested ul list from a json using a for loop in javascript,

After trying for couple of hours I was able to make it work,there are some small details i need to fix, for example my javascript is rendering all the objects as html elements, how do I render only the elements needed on the view, for example:

```
<ul class="some_class">
    <li>
        <h3>
            level_0_name => Africa
            <input type="checkbox" name="level_0_id => VALUE HERE" id="">
        </h3>
        <ul class="some_class">
            <li>
                <h3>
                    level_1_name => Company San Fracisco
                    <input type="checkbox" name="level_1_id => VALUE HERE" id="">
                </h3>
                <ul class="some_class">
                    <li>
                        <h3>
                            level_2_name => Some title
                            <input type="checkbox" name="level_2_id => VALUE HERE" id="">
                        </h3>
                        <ul class="some_class">
                            <li>
                                <h3>
                                    John Doe                                                
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="id VALUE">
                                </h3>
                            </li>
```

if you look at the http://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/3avzp6o3/3/ i created you will notice the menu starts at:

```
"level_0": [
```

and is rendering markup not needed, is there an easy way to only render the objects with an actual value like "level_1_id" => "12345" into the list?

This is the JS function:

```
function tree(data) {    
    if (typeof(data) == 'object') {        
        var ul = $('<ul>');
        for (var i in data) {            
            ul.append($('<li>').text(i).append(tree(data[i])));         
        }        
        return ul;
    } else {       
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(' => ' + data);
        return textNode;
    }
}

$(document.body).append(tree(data));
```